# Converting to a char array from int. Index's are incorrect?

Tags: java, arrays

just doing an assignment and to sum it up:
I need to get a users ID which is an int and make sure the first number is 4.

I have tried to do this by converting the id (int from the object in the main method) into the char array.

I print out the index[0] to console and it says 4, great right?

But i have made an if statement that then says if index[0]of the array is 4 then do something... it doesn't seem to acknowledge index 0 is 4 and proceeds to do whats in the else block.

```
public boolean checkID()
{
    int convert = getId(); //get id is 44444 

    char[] idArray = String.valueOf(convert).toCharArray();
    System.out.println(idArray[0]); // this returns a value of 4 in the console



    boolean check = false;
    if(idArray[0] == 4)
    {
        check = true;
        System.out.println("Id starts with 4!");
    }
    else
    {
        check = false;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Id does not start with 4");
    }

    return check;
}
```

}

Of course in the console i receive the illegal argument exception but also 4 printed out?
Sorry if this is a silly problem i have been looking at it for so long and its abit blurry now haha!
Possibly there is a better way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have declared it as char []. as @Fennec suggested you need to be checking char '4' not int 4

Comment: As @Fennec says, you need to surround your `char` with single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare an `int` with a `char`.

You have converted your `int` to an array of `char`, so the right way to see whether the first element in your array is equal 4 or not, you need to make it a char and put it inside single quotes like this:

```
 if(idArray[0] == '4')
    {
        check = true;
        System.out.println("Id starts with 4!");
    }
```

Thanks!